# How to count the number of listbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an asp page in which the are number of listboxes.I want to count the number of listboxes using Javascript and also there is another requirement,i want to disable all the listboxes in that form

Comment: Your edit is the same as your subsequent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383257/not-able-to-disable-select-box-in-html-using-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using plain javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select').length
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('select').length
```

Comment: Can't get any simpler that this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Using Protoype, you can do this:

```
$$('select').length
```