# Why is this code to disable an HTML select box not working?

Tags: javascript

```
function abc()
{
document.form1.1.disabled=true;
}
```

I have a select box whose id is `1` in my HTML page. I am using the JavaScript above but it is not disabling the select box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Fix the underlying problem. Don't have ids that start with a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("1");
elem.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

document.form1 contains a list of input elements, selectboxes and textareas. document.form1.1 is the same as saying document.form1[1] and gets the second element in that list. Try

```
document.getElementById("1").disable = true;
```